# generate random world point geometries

Tags: point, coordinates

I have a world map. I need random point geometry. So, how can I randomly generate point coordinates? Any programming language. Also, I am using SRID `4326`.

Any programming language.

Comment: Do you just need a single point?

Comment: Yes, but it should be absolutely random coordinate.

Comment: But algorthm for n points will be also a good choice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With some Python:

```
from random import uniform
x, y = uniform(-180,180), uniform(-90, 90)
```

or for a loop:

```
def newpoint():
   return uniform(-180,180), uniform(-90, 90)

points = (newpoint() for x in xrange(10))
for point in points:
   print point
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution.